# Xamarin Picasso, The name `context' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, picasso

I am trying to use Picasso on my solution to display an image:

```
Picasso.With(context).Load("http://example.com/image.jpg").Into(imageview);
```

But I get this: The name `context' does not exist in the current context (CS0103). Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I am really new to Xamarin development and C#. I have installed the package from nuget and have included the Square.Picasso directive on my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside of an activity you may be able to retrieve the context with getContext().  If that doesn't work, you will need to pass it into your class or get the context some other way.  I recommend research what context is in Android. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Context

```
Picasso.With(getContext()).Load("http://example.com/image.jpg").Into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your android.content.Context to it. Read the Picasso documentation to know more about it:

[Picasso Documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/)

Comment: Thanks, just realised that I had to use With(Application.Context)